# Nextflow: how to create many-to-many tuple for process

Tags: nextflow

Using `Nextflow`, I need to submit `x * y` jobs where `x` is the number of input `.bam` files and `y` is the number of genome intervals (e.g., `<chrom>:<start>-<end>`). i.e., for every `.bam` file, submit a single job for every defined interval.

I have tried a few variations with no luck (see below).

**Ultimate question:** For each `.bam` file, how do I submit a single job for every defined genome interval using `NextFlow`?

### Attempts

**Attempt 1 (submit both as individual `Channels`):**

Only submits one `.bam` for all intervals.

```
sample_bams = Channel.fromPath(sample_input_path + "*.bam")
intervals = Channel.from(['1:10000-20000', '5:55555-77777'])
PROC(sample_bams, intervals)
```

**Attempt 2 (submit as tuple of mapped `Channel`s):**

Submits only 10 jobs and fails because the interval `Channel` is passed as `DataflowBroadcast around DataflowStream[?]` object. The `PROC` was changed to receive a tuple rather than individual arguments.

```
sample_interval_tuples = Channel.fromPath(sample_input_path + "*.bam")
                         .map { sample_file -> tuple(sample_file, align_to_ref, DRF_jar, Channel.from(['1:10000-20000', '5:55555-77777'])) }
```

**Attempt 3 (submit as tuple of mapped `.bam`s to non-`Channel` of intervals)**:

Submits 10 jobs and fails because the intervals are passed as a single list. The `PROC` was changed to receive a tuple rather than individual arguments.

```
sample_interval_tuples = Channel.fromPath(sample_input_path + "*.bam")
                         .map { sample_file -> tuple(sample_file, align_to_ref, DRF_jar, ['1:10000-20000', '5:55555-77777']) }
```

Really appreciate your help!

related query: for DSL v2, we wouldn't include from combined_inputs in the input, yeah?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [combine](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#combine) operator can be used to produce the Cartesian product:

```
sample_bams = Channel.fromPath( './path/to/bams/*.bam' )
intervals = Channel.of( '1:10000-20000', '5:55555-77777' )

sample_bams
    .combine(intervals)
    .set { combined_inputs }


process test {

    echo true

    input:
    tuple path(bam), val(interval) from combined_inputs

    """
    echo -n "${interval} ${bam}"
    """
}
```

Regarding the related query: Correct. The from and into 'bind' declarations can be omitted

Comment: we should crown Steve as King Of Nextflow Answers

Answer (score 2):

I think this cheat sheet might help:
https://github.com/danrlu/Nextflow_cheatsheet/blob/main/nextflow_cheatsheet.pdf

Comment:  Love the cheat sheet!